# Aren't the suggested objectives of 40 to 80 items to review per day in review queues too ambitious?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

*Low quality answers*, *Suggested edits*, *First questions*, *Triage*...
To the member willing to help, each review queue suggests to study from 40 to 80 entries a day.

I'm impressed and praise those who perform these reviews regularly,
but when I'm doing some, I can hardly go over 10 or 15 posts reviewed a day. Else it would lower the quality of my study.
10 posts to study and comment or edit, if needed, for some, it's maybe 20 minutes?

When I look at these 40 or 80 reviews for objective, per thematic, I find them destabilizing: an heavy burden in front of me.
A work that only few SO members, I think, are able to complete.

---

The idea I want to defend here is that the number of suggested reviews per day should be reduced to a number more accessible for more SO members.

This, to encourage a greater number of them to complete one of these tasks.
I think that stopping each time at `11 to 40` or `13 to 80` reviews for a queue, with a good job done but the feeling of incompleteness given by these indicators, is discouraging.

Myself, I think that 10 reviews suggested by day per review queue is enough. But it's to discuss.

Comment: Are you talking about [this bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R905C.png)? If so, that shows the maximum number of reviews you can do in a day, not a suggested target for you to reach.

Comment: @SuperStormer Yes. But for me, I understand it like: "_the amount of reviews a SO member willing to do a good 'civic duty' is expected to do_"

Comment: Again, this is the maximum. That's it. What you interpret it as is not what it is meant as. I'm not sure what is there to discuss here.

Comment: If you see a limit and treat it as a quota... well, now you understand why the system doesn't bother to award reputation for doing a good job.

Comment: Similar misreads occur with health recommendations regarding alcohol intake per week: The maximum intake is read as the ***recommended*** intake...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you see there is not the suggested number of reviews you should perform but rather the **maximum number of reviews** you can do in a given day.

Allowing users to review an arbitrary number of posts will be prone to abuse and hence a suitable rate limit is needed. Given there is a limit due to this it is important to show it to the user in case they do hit it.

I agree though that showing it as a progress bar gives somewhat of a message implying it as a target to be achieved. If you have a suggestion on how the limit can be shown so that the messaging is more clear please raise a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).